# BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic() always returns false.

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an Android app to talk with an Arduino using BLE.  I have been able to scan devices, connect to the target, discover services, get characteristics, and read those that are readable.  However, when I try to write a writeable characteristics, the method always returns false.  When I debugged into the android.bluetooth code, the following sequence occurs: 
characteristic.getService().getDevice always returns null, 
which causes the writeCharacteristic to fail.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What Android version? 4.3, 4.4?

Comment: my case is: write a characteristic then read it, works well, but read characteristic then write not work. my code is here: `writeCharacteristic(mBluetoothGatt.getService(ACCL_UUID_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(ACCL_UUID_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_NAME),
                "hi7111".getBytes());`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please check your objects in the corresponding sequence. I keep only the BluetoothGatt object and create BluetoothGattService and BluetoothGattCharacteristic every time I need to write to the BLE device.

```
byte[] data_to_write; // Your data
BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SREVICE);
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
BluetoothDevice mDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(....);
BluetoothGatt mBG = mDevice.connectGatt(....);

BluetoothGattService mSVC = mBG.getService(service_uuid);
BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCH = mSVC.getCharacteristic(characteristic_uuid);
mCH.setValue(data_to_write);
mBG.writeCharacteristic(mCH);
```

Comment: how to get characteristic_uuid and service_uuid?

Comment: that's what you define for yourself, or you should look up on the bluetooth homepage what the common 16 but uuids are

Comment: this is work for me but after many read and write, write method does not do anything. why?

Comment: it works for me if I set the delay for the  bluetooth.getBluetoothGatt().writeCharacteristic(mCH); 
 method!!
have any idea?

Comment: I'm doing mine this way, and it works for one characteristic but not the other. both are write only, so they should both be writeable

Comment: This answer doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Some characterictics are just not writeable. 
The code above should use some side effect. (not the same characterictics or ...)