# Unable to read measurement from my BLE device, writeCharacteristic always returns false

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to read the data taken from a BLE scale after the measurement.
If I try to read the model name everything works.

Pearing correctly. I receive the confirmation message correctly on the display of the successful date setting. After the measurement, the device exposes the services and I use a simple button to start the connection via address.

```
buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String deviceAddress = "B4:99:4C:6E:20:68";
            BluetoothDevice device =  getBluetoothAdapter(getApplicationContext()).getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
            connectToDevice(device, false);
        }
    });
```

connection via GATT

```
public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device, boolean pairing) {

        if (mGatt == null) {
            mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallbackNoPairing);

    }
}
```

callBack method called by connectGatt

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallbackNoPairing = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                gatt.discoverServices();

                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        Log.i("Callback", "onServicesDiscovered");

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(ADGattUUID.WeightScaleService).getCharacteristic(ADGattUUID.WeightScaleMeasurement);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(ADGattUUID.ClientCharacteristicConfiguration);

        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        boolean result = gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
         Log.i("writeDescriptor", String.valueOf(result));
    }
```

when I arrive at this point and execute writeCharacteristic, I always get false

```
    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor,
                                  int status) {
        Log.i("Callback", "onDescriptorWrite");
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(ADGattUUID.WeightScaleService).getCharacteristic(ADGattUUID.WeightScaleMeasurement);
        characteristic.setValue(new byte[]{1, 1});
        boolean result1 = gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
        Log.i("writeCharacteristic", String.valueOf(result1));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                                characteristic) {
        Log.i("Callback", "onCharacteristicChanged");
        Log.i("onCharacteristicChanged", new String(characteristic.getValue()));

    }
};
```

Indeed in the documentation it is indicated as "Indicate". So how do I recover this data?

[image]

value read
[image: value read]

Ok, I was able to decode the measurement using the following class

```
public static Bundle readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    int flag = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
    String flagString = Integer.toBinaryString(flag);
    int offset=0;
    for(int index = flagString.length(); 0 < index ; index--) {
        String key = flagString.substring(index-1 , index);

        if(index == flagString.length()) {
            double convertValue = 0;
            if(key.equals("0")) {
                bundle.putString(ADGattService.KEY_UNIT, VALUE_WEIGHT_SCALE_UNITS_KG);
                convertValue = 0.005f;
            }
            else {
                bundle.putString(ADGattService.KEY_UNIT, VALUE_WEIGHT_SCALE_UNITS_LBS);
                convertValue = 0.01f;
            }
            // Unit
            offset+=1;

            // Value
            double value = (double)(characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, offset)) * convertValue;
            bundle.putDouble("weight", value);
            offset+=2;
        }
        else if(index == flagString.length()-1) {
            if(key.equals("1")) {


            }
            else {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

            }
        }
        else if(index == flagString.length()-2) {
            if(key.equals("1")) {
                offset+=1;
            }
        }
        else if(index == flagString.length()-3) {
            if(key.equals("1")) {
                // BMI and Height
            }
        }
    }
    return bundle;
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm you are doing this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23886591/5184092

Comment: What are the characteristic properties? Is it writable?

Comment: I'm not very practical with Android. I have followed various guides on the internet like this https://medium.com/@avigezerit/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-22bc7310387a. 
The device I use is A&D uc-352 ble. 
I also tried the way shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23886591/5184092, 
but I always get the same thing

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. The WeightMeasurement characteristic is not writable. So obviously that returns false...

Comment: So how do I go about reading it?

Comment: Well, first of all you need to turn on the indication, but in your code you are enabling the notification and not the indication! Then you need to call gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(descriptor, true). More information about turning on indications/notification can be found here: https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-3-117d3a8aee23 . After that you will receive the measurement in onCharacteristicChanged and you must decode the byte array according to the specification.

Comment: @MartijnvanWelie, i was able to read. I get a series of bytes that you see in the image. Now how do I turn this information into weight? I'm trying in various ways but I don't get anything significant.

Comment: @MartijnvanWelie i have read and coded the measurement. Now the strange thing is that I can no longer receive the measurement. I always get the error I/gattCallback: Status: 19